# How do I change my Background.Color to Gray for one row in my GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to change the Background Color for one row in my GridView. My GridView is defined in my code.behind file:

```
Dim boundColumn As BoundField = New BoundField With {
                .HeaderText = "Color",
                .DataField = "Color"
                }
        GridView1.Columns.Add(boundColumn)

        Dim txt1732Column = new TemplateField With {
                .ItemTemplate = new TextColumn("myTextBox1732"),
                .HeaderText = "17/32"
                }
        GridView1.Columns.Add(txt1732Column)

        Dim txt3564Column = new TemplateField With {
                .ItemTemplate = new TextColumn("myTextBox3564"),
                .HeaderText = "35/64"
                }
        GridView1.Columns.Add(txt3564Column)

        Dim txt916Column = new TemplateField With {
                .ItemTemplate = new TextColumn("myTextBox916"),
                .HeaderText = "9/16"
                }
        GridView1.Columns.Add(txt916Column)

<Snip>...</Snip>

Class TextColumn
Implements ITemplate

Private ReadOnly _myName As String

Public Sub New(myName As String)
    _myName = myName
End Sub

Public Sub InstantiateIn(container As Control) Implements ITemplate.InstantiateIn
    Dim txt As New TextBox
    txt.ID = _myName
    txt.Columns = 3
    container.Controls.Add(txt)
End Sub
```

End Class

I need row.index 1 to be gray in background color. I have tried several methods:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            If row.RowIndex = 1 Then
                row.Style.Add("background-color","gray")
                row.BackColor = Color.Gray
                row.Cells(1).BackColor = Color.Gray
                Dim myTextBox1932 As TextBox = row.Cells(1).FindControl("myTextBox1932")
                myTextBox1932.BackColor = Color.Gray
                myTextBox1932.Style.Add("background-color","gray")
```

... with no luck. This GridView displays, but row index 1 is not gray. Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at [RowDataBound](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound?view=netframework-4.7.2) event

Comment: Thank you very much @Dle that did the trick

Comment: Glad it helped, you could post an answer of your own explaining what went wrong and how you fixed, and then mark that answer as the 'good one', this way future readers will be able to fix their issues at a first glance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my situation I moved my code from page_Load to the RowDataBound event handler.

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    If row.RowIndex = 1 Then
        row.BackColor = Color.Gray
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray
```